# I don't know where my next mission is

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I can't find out what my next mission is for GTA V. I'm 26.4% into the game.

The last mission I played that wasn't one of Lester's missions was mini sub. If you don't know which mission that is, it's the 29th mission. Here is a video about it:

Comment: Did you try switching characters and complete their missions?

Comment: Do I need to do the strangers and freaks missions

Comment: No, those are just side missions. If you want to COMPLETELY finish the game, then yes, do the Strangers and Freaks missions.

Answer (score 5):

Just follow the symbols on the map. If it's Franklin's mission is has a green F symbol. Michael's have blue M symbols while Trevor's missions use a red T symbol.

The "Strangers and Freaks" missions are shown with question marks in the character's color. Sometimes they are required to advance the plot and get more missions available to the player.